# Google Sheets query with sum and date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to write a query from the following table:

[image: Transactions]

columns for date (A), description (B), amount (C), category (D)

I have this query:

```
=query(Transactions!A2:D501, "select D, sum(C) group by D",0)
```

I need help with adding a date filter where the date is greater than or equal the date in a specific cell. I am running into a wall with this and need help modifying my query to include the date filter.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. We already have many questions about Google Sheets, many about using the QUERY function and a few about exactly what you are asking as the one linked in the post notice.  If, after reading the linked question, you are still struggling with setting a date filter in QUERY, please express your filter criteria using Google Sheets formula sintax; in other words, be specific about which cell should be used in the filter and try to build the filter by yourself by using the concatenate operator `&`, the TEXT function as is shown in both answers to the linked question.